# QGIS 3.16.6 : Couldn't load SIP module

Tags: qgis

On Windows 10, during the startup of QGIS 3.16, I am used to encounter an issue about python :

```
Couldn't load SIP module.
Python support will be disabled.

Traceback (most recent call last):
File "", line 1, in
File "C:/PROGRA1/QGIS31.16/apps/qgis-ltr/./python\qgis_init_.py", line 70, in
from qgis.PyQt import QtCore
File "C:/PROGRA1/QGIS31.16/apps/qgis-ltr/./python\qgis\PyQt\QtCore.py", line 24, in
from PyQt5.QtCore import *
ImportError: DLL load failed: The specified procedure could not be found.
```

I have encountered this issue with previous version of QGIS and was able to get rid off it by installing an up-to-date QGIS version but after a while this error came back. If this issue shows up, QGIS doesn't load the geoprocessing tools and becomes mostly unusable.

Answer (score 1):

If you are also an anaconda user, the source of this issue could come from here, when python packages are updated by anaconda.
In my situation, I was able to fix the problem by deleting thoses folders:

```
C:\Users\%USERNAME%\AppData\Roaming\QGIS
C:\Users\%USERNAME%\AppData\Roaming\Python
```

Reference : https://github.com/qgis/QGIS/issues/31367